# increment how many times an image is displayed in a picturebox

Tags: c#

I'm trying to display an image using a button click and increment a variable when a certain image is shown, but with the code below the variable num is always 0.

my code

```
    int num = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int x = 0;

    PictureBox[] pictureBoxs = new PictureBox[4];

    Random rnd = new Random();


    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        pictureBoxs[0] = pbimg1;
        pictureBoxs[1] = pbimg2;
        pictureBoxs[2] = pbimg3;
        pictureBoxs[3] = pbimg4;

       x = rnd.Next(2);

    }


    public void displaypics()
    {
        pictureBoxs[i].Image = imageList1.Images[x];
    }



    private void btn2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {
        i=1;

        displaypics();

        if (pictureBoxs[i].Image == imageList1.Images[1])
        {
            num++;
        }

        if (num == 2)
        {
            tb1.Visible = true;
            tb1.Text = "GAME OVER!" + num;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is most likely that num is being instantiated to zero everytime the class is being instantiated

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the context is in which that piece of code is used. So I guess what should solve this would be adding `x = rnd.Next(2)` to the btn2_Click method. Making it look like this:

```
private void btn2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    x = rnd.Next(2);
    displaypics();

    if (pictureBoxs[i].Image == imageList1.Images[1])
    {
        num++;
    }

    if (num == 2)
    {
        tb1.Visible = true;
        tb1.Text = "GAME OVER!" + num;
    }

    i++;
}
```

Maybe you could give some more details on what that control should do/how it's used.

Comment: im creating a Strike It Lucky game. I have 2 images that randomly go into picture boxes when the user clicks the buttons and if they get the image for "hotspot" a certain amount of times they lose. But i cant get the variable to count how many times the image shows.

Comment: @user3714831 from your code I can see that you've 4 pictures. Out of those four pictures two will be displayed each time the user clicks the button, right?

Comment: no only 2 pictures at this stage which display randomly in the picture boxes. Trying to get the variable "num" to increment when 1 of them displays, but its always 0. Only 1 pic shows at a time btw.

Comment: @user3714831 in that case I'm not understanding your code. In the constructor you set 4 images, and where does 'imageList1' come from?

Comment: sry I'm new at this. The imageList1 is an imagelist on the form with 2 pics in it. The 4 is picture boxes not images.

Comment: in that case replacing your method with my edited (added `x = rnd.Next(2)`, `i++` and removed `i = 1;`) version should make it work.

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you set breakpoints and step through the code? Is the int set as 0, or does it contain the updated value?

Comment: The value is always 0

Comment: Right now, every time the program runs it is setting the value num to 0. You need to store the value somewhere where it won't be lost. If it's on a windows form, try using a hidden label or text field that your program reads the value from and then updates. Or you can try storing it in a text file.

Comment: Also, is the program exiting every time it runs? If so, the value wouldn't be stored in memory anywhere.

Comment: well then, the instance of the class you are using is being cleaned up after it is no longer referenced. You need to store the values somewhere else. Can you also post the entirety of the code file you have there - as somebody else stated you aren't providing much context in the code you have provided.